# Trying to create a success message after form submission in js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

The success message is always there. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I want the message to appear after the submit button is pressed and then disappear on page refresh. I'm new to coding as you can probably tell.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const successMessage = document.querySelector('#form');
form.addEventListener('submitt', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    successMessage.classList.add('show');
    setTimeout(() => form.submit(), 2000);
} );
```

```css
#success-message {
    display: none;
}
#success-message.show {
    display: block;
}
.success_text {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
    <div class="form-style-6">
        <p class="success_text">
            Success!
        </p>
        <form id="form" action="main.html/form" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Contact Us</legend>
            <div class="asterisk_firstname">
            <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" name="user_firstName" required>
            </div>
            <div class="asterisk_lastname">
            <label for="latName">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" name="user_lastName" required>
            </div>
            <div class="asterisk_email">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="user_email" required>
            </div>
            <label for="role">Position:</label>
            <select id="role" name="user_role">
                <option value="none">-Select-</option>
                <option value="account_manager">Account Manager</option>
                <option value="project_manager">Project Manager</option>
                <option value="developer">Developer</option>
                <option value="quality analyst">Quality Analyst</option>
            </select>
            <label for="comment">Note:</label>
            <textarea id="comment" name="user_comment"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" id="submitt">Submit</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Typo: `submitt`

Comment: Why *wouldn't* the success message be shown? I don't see anything that would hide it. The CSS you posted doesn't hide `<p class="success_text">`. `#success-message { display: none;}` would, but I don't see what that's selecting in your example.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS is trying to target an element with `id="success-message"` which doesn’t exist in the HTML.

Instead the CSS should target the HTML element which has `class="success_text"`, like this:

```
.success_text {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.success_text.show {
    display: block;
}
```

The JavaScript also needs changing in order to select the correct element, like this:

```
const successMessage = document.querySelector('.form-style-6 .success_text');
```

Finally, correct the `submitt` typo in addEventListener:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

**Correct this section**

```
form.addEventListener('submit',()=>{
 e.preventDefault();
    successMessage.classList.add('show');
    setTimeout(() => form.submit(), 2000);
}
)
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <p class="success_text">
            Success!
 </p>
```

Your class name is "success-text" and you should use that instead "#success-message"
and you will be good to go. Also addEventListener("submit" cb) should be use instead of "submitt"

Answer (score 0):

@Plasmid Squid this is natural behavior in web development for POST the form data via javascript you can achieve your goal via XMLHttpRequest like this

First Step - HTML Part

---

You can set HTML Form Tag & its element like this

```
<form id="form" action="#" method="POST" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="user_firstName" required>
    <button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Second Step -  Javascript Part

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');
    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
        
        var form = document.getElementById('form');
        var formData = new FormData(form);
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {

                var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText)
                if( response.success == true ){

                    alert("Success Message");

                }else{

                    // Show Errors or False Message
                }
            }
        }
        xhttp.open("POST", "receive.php",true);
        xhttp.send(formData);

    });
</script>
```

you have to just replace **receive.php** with your form action attribute value